# After updating the password, many programs asking me to enter the new password

Tags: password, keychain, apple-watch

After updating the password, many programs asking me to enter the new password. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

And outlook also asked to update something

[image]

[image]

After updating the password, I cannot use Apple Watch to unlock my Macbook Pro.

[image]

It is quite weird that MacOS keeps asking me to change passwords for some months and later the system seems to forget I have updated the password.

Comment: Which password did you change (login password, iCloud password, keychain password ...) and how?

Comment: @nohillside The login password via "Uses & Group". Later, many programmes asking me to update and I cannot use Apple Watch to unlock my Macbook Pro.

Comment: You seem to at least need to update the Keychain password as well, see last screenshot.

Comment: The system can't unlock it when they aren't in sync - if you log out and log back in do you get a prompt to have them match?

Comment: @EzekielElin I did not try it. I will try logging out and logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur when your keychain and account passwords go out of sync. The system may try to help you reconcile this if you log out, then log back into your account. You should get a prompt indicating the passwords don't match, and will be able to correct this.